# My name, my name, it's a guessing game!

Tags: knowledge, music

I needn't be late, that would be bad
As a man with a job, I must get to work

I must travel quickly now, so I go
I travel by the underground train

I have bills that I need to pay
I need that money to live

My name is just a name, it's rather dull
If you feel lonely, as I do, feel free to give me a call

---

Can you guess the speaker's name?

Please explain every line in your answer, and good luck solving!

Comment: Dear @Rewan Demontay ,Can you  add a hint?This is really an interesting puzzle but I have no direction how to solve it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, it's only a try

> The speaker is (or is related to) the **ABBA** pop group

I needn't be late, that would be bad As a man with a job, I must get to work

> *SOS* song by ABBA (of course, a SOS signal must be responded very quickly, otherwise it can turn bad).

I must travel quickly now, so I go I travel by the underground train

> *Waterloo* by ABBA (it's a London Underground station).

I have bills that I need to pay I need that money to live

> *Money, Money, Money* by ABBA (probably no explanation needed).

My name is just a name, it's rather dull If you feel lonely, as I do, feel free to give me a call

> *Take a Chance on Me* by ABBA; and the name of the group is... well, rather dull, since it's a mere abbreviation.

Bonus:

> The `knowledge` and `music` tags not only show that one need some knowledge in music to answer the question, bus also probably reference *Knowing Me, Knowing You* and *Thank You For The Music* songs, also performed by ABBA.